# Dask: Drop NAs on columns?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, dask

I have tried to apply a filter to remove columns with too many NAs to my dask dataframe:

```
df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', thresh=round(len(df) * .8))
```

Unfortunately it seems that the dask `dropna` API is slightly different from that of pandas and does not accept either an `axis` nor a `threshold`.
One partial way around it is to iterate column by column and remove those that are constant (regardless of whether they are filled with NAs or not, as I do not mind getting rid of constants):

```
    for col in df.columns:
        if len(df[col].unique()) == 1:
            new_df = df.drop(col, axis = 1)
```

But this does not let me apply a threshold. I could compute the threshold manually by adding:

```
elif sum(df[col].isnull().compute()) / len(df[col]) > 0.8:
    new_df = df.drop(col, axis = 1)
```

But I'm not sure calling `compute` and `len` at this point would be optimal and I would be curious to know if there are any better ways to go about this ?

Answer (score 5):

## Update 10 Aug 2021:

Now Dask has `axis`, `thresh`, and `subset` args that may help. The previous answer can be rewritten as:

```
df.dropna(subset=columns_to_inspect, thresh=threshold_to_drop_na, axis=1)
```

## Old answer

You're right, there is no way to do this by using `df.dropna()`.

I would suggest using this equation
`df.loc[:,df.isnull().sum()<THRESHOLD]`

Comment: Does anyone know if 'axis' was added to dask.dataframe.dropna?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin, [It's there now.](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: @StarukhinYaroslav I don't see `axis` on the link you provided, and [in docs it is described](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.dropna.html) as "Not supported in Dask". Although I think that it is very unusual to describe features not supported in a way this documentation does it, it's easy to got mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem and used the following code:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].isnull().all().compute()=True:
        df = df.drop(col,axis=1)
```

Comment: This operation is extremely slow for large dataset

Comment: You are correct - however if you need to clean up your columns - you might not have any other option

Answer (score 1):

> df.loc[:,df.isnull().sum()<THRESHOLD]

produces KeyError, because you need to compute the indexer:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,\n        True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,  True],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

combining the answers of skibee and Starukhin Yaroslav, I use:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.isna().all().compute()]
```

if you want to use a threshold you can use:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.isna().sum().compute() > THRESHOLD]
```